# Angular2 routerLink

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been messing with Angular 2 and got stuck. Front page has list of topics to learn (TopicsComponent) .Clicking them will trigger path: '**' for now.  PageNotFoundComponent also uses TopicsComponent to show topics but routerLink wont work anymore.

Example: in front page when i click angular2 link i get url **/angular2**. But when PageNotFoundComponent is active i get url **/angular2/(angular2)**

Here is the code:

**main.ts**

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { appRouterProviders }   from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [appRouterProviders]);
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';

import { TopicsComponent } from './topics/topics.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './notfound/page-not-found.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [

 {
  path: '',
  component: TopicsComponent
 },
 {
  path: '**',
  component: PageNotFoundComponent
 }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TopicsService } from './shared/topics.service';
import { TopicsComponent } from './topics/topics.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './notfound/page-not-found.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [KoodikoguService],
  precompile: [TopicsComponent, PageNotFoundComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**topics.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TopicsService } from './shared/topics.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'topics',
  templateUrl: 'app/topics/topics.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] 

})

export class TopicsComponent { 
    title = 'Welcome to the topics component!';
    topics:any;

    constructor(private _dataService: TopicsService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._dataService.getTopics().then(topics => this.topics = topics);
    }

}
```

**topics.component.html**

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

<div *ngFor="let topic of topics">
    <a [routerLink]="topic.title" routerLinkActive="active">{{ topic.title }}</a>
</div>
```

**page-not-found.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { TopicsComponent } from '../topics/topics.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'not-found',
  templateUrl: 'app/notfound/page-not-found.component.html',
  directives: [TopicsComponent]

})
export class PageNotFoundComponent { }
```

**page-not-found.component.ts**

```
<h1>Page not found!</h1>

<topics></topics>
```

Comment: What's the value of `topic.title`?

Comment: topic.title = 'angular2'

Comment: Try `[routerLink]="'/' + topic.title"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding pathMatch to your default route and make sure your html file has a base href '/' instead of '.' if that is being used.

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig }  from '@angular/router';

import { TopicsComponent } from './topics/topics.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './notfound/page-not-found.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [

 {
  path: '',
  component: TopicsComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 {
  path: '**',
  component: PageNotFoundComponent
 }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
  provideRouter(routes)
];
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs like this: '/angular2/(angular2)' are meant to indicate the path to two different RouterOutlets, the default outlet outside the parens, and a secondary/auxilary outlet inside the parens.  Not sure why this is happening in your code though, since I don't see any RouterOutlets.  Can you put an example up on Plunker (or some other site that lets you do Angular2 sample apps)?